# How to make a Google Map move behind a sticky header when scrolling

Tags: html, css, google-maps, scroll

So I have a sticky header implemented using CSS and a long HTML page. At the bottom of the page is a `<div>` element containing a Google Map.

When I scroll down the page, all content moves behind the sticky header as you'd expect, except for the Google Map, which moves on top of it.

What do I have to do to get the Google Map to move behind the sticky header when scrolling in the same way that the other elements do?

Comment: have you tried adjusting `z-index` of map/sticker?

Comment: I haven't done anything to the map yet - just copied the example from the Google Maps API site.

Comment: Well, do something then.

Comment: I mean I haven't modified any of the properties of the map or containing `<div>`. This is my question - what do I need to change in order to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Map container z-index: -1;

Header container z-index: 999;

be sure to add position to both.

Comment: No problem. Hope all goes well!